# jQuery autocomplete - assigning one JSON PHP array to multiple HTML ID tags

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, autocomplete, latitude-longitude

I have successfully setup a jQuery autocomplete call from a PHP file using JSON encode. I am successfully sending a KVP (Key Value Pair) array back to my HTML.

The issue I have, is that I wish to send part of the array items to one id="sometag1" and the other array items to id="sometag2" and id="sometag3".

Here is my javascript jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(data) {
        $('#edit-ad-location').autocomplete({
            source: '/postcodes-latlong.php',
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
```

The file "postcodes-latlong.php" contains the following code:

```
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
    $new_row = $row['post_title'];
    if ($new_row != $this_row) {
        $data[] = array(
                'id' => $row['meta_id'],
                'label' => $row['post_title'] ,
                'value' => $row['post_title'] ,
            );
        }
    if ($row['meta_key'] == "_aphs_FYN_latitude") {
    $data[count($data) -1]["geo-search-lat"] = $row['meta_value'];

    }
    if ($row['meta_key'] == "_aphs_FYN_longitude") {
        $data[count($data) -1]["geo-search-lng"] = $row['meta_value'];
    }
    $this_row = $row['post_title'];
    }
}


// jQuery wants JSON data
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

If the **term** `4000` is passed, we get the following returning array:

```
[{
       "id":"364307",
        "label":"4000, BRISBANE",
        "value":"4000, BRISBANE",
        "geo-search-lat":"-27.46758",
        "geo-search-lng":"153.027892"
      },{
        "id":"364322",
        "label":"4000, BRISBANE ADELAIDE STREET",
        "value":"4000, BRISBANE ADELAIDE STREET",
        "geo-search-lat":"-27.466517",
        "geo-search-lng":"153.027495"
      },{
        "id":"364337",
        "label":"4000, SPRING HILL",
        "value":"4000, SPRING HILL",
        "geo-search-lat":"-27.460873",
        "geo-search-lng":"153.024454"
}]
```

What I am trying to achieve, is send the ID, label and value to the autocomplete field with id: "#edit-ad-location" - this works fine.

I also wish to send the latitude and longitude values to two other id tags #geo-search-lat and #geo-search-lng as shown below:

```
`<div .... id="geo-search-lat" value=""> </div>`
```

and

```
`<div .... id="geo-search-lng" value=""> </div>`
```

I have tried doing the following (using 3 separate tags, one for each id) but this doesn't work:

```
`jQuery(document).ready(function(data){
    $('#edit-ad-location', '#geo-search-lat', '#geo-search-lng').autocomplete({source:'/postcodes-latlong.php', minLength:2});
});`
```

How do I pass the geo-search-lat and geo-search-lng values from the returned JSON array to:

```
mapDiv.gmap3({
                        getgeoloc:{
                            callback : function(latLng){
                                if (latLng){
                                    jQuery('#geo-search-lat').val(latLng.lat());
                                    jQuery('#geo-search-lng').val(latLng.lng());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I see somthing wrong with your php code: `$data[] = array_push($data...)` is incorrect, it inserts numbers in the array. Please fix and report the JSON (PHP code becomes irrelevant once your JSON is fixed).

Comment: Also: _I wish to send the latitude and longitude values to two other id tags_ What is the expected behavior? Do you want to fill the fields when user chooses an option from the list (e.g. user selects "4503, KALLANGUR" and the other two boxes get filled with -27.25075 and 152.99) or do you want something else?

Comment: After spending many hours troubleshooting this, I noticed the following jQuery code that may help:
mapDiv.gmap3({
      getgeoloc:{
       callback : function(latLng){
        if (latLng){
         jQuery('#geo-search-lat').val(latLng.lat());
         jQuery('#geo-search-lng').val(latLng.lng());
        }
       }
      }
     });

Comment: I wish to send the latitudinal and longitudinal values to the div tag so we have: id="geo-search-lat" value="-27.25075" and id="geo-search-lng" value="152.99" - these values are passed in the HTML request.
Also, I have tried "array_merge", "array_splice" and I have not been able to get the data "inserted" into the array. It seems to add it to the end but not "inside" the array.

Comment: You wish to fill the textboxes _after_ the user selects an option from the list, correct? As for your PHP issue, I _think_ (not tested) you can simply add the keys like this: `$data[count($data) -1]["geo-search-lat"] = <meta_value>`.

Answer (score 0):

yes that is correct. When the first field auto-completes and a suburb/postcode is selected (onClick), then the other two `<div id="geo-search-lat" value=""> and <div id="geo-search-lng" value="">` tags' values get populated based on the returned values from the JSON array. I will test the php modification as suggested and get back to you...

Comment: You are a real brain!! This worked:

`code` if ($row['meta_key'] == "_aphs_FYN_latitude") {
 $data[count($data) -1]["geo-search-lat"] = $row['meta_value'];

 }
 if ($row['meta_key'] == "_aphs_FYN_longitude") {
  $data[count($data) -1]["geo-search-lng"] = $row['meta_value'];
 }
`/code`

Comment: So I still have the issue of passing part of the JSON array to the autocomplete field, and the rest of the array to the other 2 DIV ID tags.

But I have this code that could help push things forward:

`code`

           mapDiv.gmap3({
      getgeoloc:{
       callback : function(latLng){
        if (latLng){
         jQuery('#geo-search-lat').val(latLng.lat());
         jQuery('#geo-search-lng').val(latLng.lng());
        }
       }
      }
     });